# Show that $1,2,...,121$ can't be arranged such that they satisfy some properties

Tags: combinatorics

Let a $11$x$11$- square , that have $121$ mini-squares, and the numbers from $1$ to $121$.

Show that they can't be arranged such that two consecutive numbers stay in two mini squares that have a common edge and the numbers $1^2$, $2^2$,...,$11^2$ stay on the same column.

I think that on the line that contains $10^2$ are  numbers between $90$ and $110$.

Also on the line that contains $9^2$ are numbers between $71$ and $91$ and so on.

I don't know how it can help me.

Comment: @Mark Bennet I don't understand what means differences. Also what is the contradicton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the numbers $1^2$ through to $11^2$ fill one column. This divides the square into two parts. There are ten differences between consecutive squares, and these differences are all odd. There are an even number of distinct integers strictly between two consecutive squares.

Now at each square other than $1$ and $121$ the chain of successive digits must cross the line of squares eg $3\to 4\to 5$ and $8\to 9 \to 10$ (can't go vertically in the line of squares). Say we go left from $1$, then on the left we accumulate the differences $2, 6, 10, 14, 18$ which total $50$ and this is not divisible by $11$ - and the differences on the right are $4+8+12+16+20=60$ and this isn't divisible by $11$ either.

Comment: Can you try to explain with many words and details?( because your argument is very short and hard to understand for me)

Comment: @Problemsolving. There are eleven rows, so the squares will completely fill one column and there will be whole columns of squares to left and right. Each of these columns will contain eleven squares so the number of squares on the left will be a number of whole columns, hence a multiple of $11$. The chain will start at $1$. After passing through $2$ and $3$ it will reach $4$. To exit from $4$ the chain has to pass to the other side of the column of squares. Then through four more $5,6,7,8$ before reaching $9$ where it similarly has to pass to the other side to exit. Keep going and add up.

Comment: Now is clear. Thank you!

Comment: I have a problem.....What happened if $1^2,...,11^2$ are on the first column or the last column?

Comment: @Problemsolving Then when you go from $1$ to $4$ you don't have anywhere to go after.

Answer (score 1):

[image: best case scenario]

When we start filling up the $7^{th}$ row (with parts of row $8$) we block off the green tiles. So we can not fill them up later (two consecutive numbers have to stay in two mini squares that have a common edge). Thus we can easily see that it can not be so that $2$ consecutive numbers stay in two mini squares that have a common edge and the numbers $1^2, 2^2,...,11^2$ stay on the same column. Hope you liked it!
**P.S.** I had no *suitable* tool for doing this so I had to do this in Microsoft Word. And to color the boxes I had to type $X$s and then highlight it (my Microsoft Excel needs to be updated). Hope this is not inconvenient for you.

---

**Edit:** Excel is back on. However understand that my presented case was the best case. Here I have included on exactly why and another which shows where you are *bound* to get stuck.

[image: In response]

Comment: Zuhai Khan  Why you wrote $1^2$,...,$11^2$ in that order?

Comment: @Problemsolving I thought you said that they have to stay on the same column. Column $6$ was the best place for numbering them and this order ensures that I can write as many numbers as possible before closing off certain areas of the square.

Comment: @ Mohammad Zuhair Khan You put them in the ascending order on that column. You could write $1, 5^2, 3^2,...$ for example.

Comment: @Problemsolving Yes, but even then there would be parts of the square closed off. The way I arranged it ensured that I could write the maximum numbers before closing off the gap. Wait, I'll include an arrangement with $1, 9, 4$ to show how this much could cause a problem, alongside a $81, 121, 100$ arrangement.

Comment: I need an argument good for all the cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71867/discussion-between-mohammad-zuhair-khan-and-problemsolving).